# Moq: Using the CallBase() for a method with parameters and a return value to perfrom the original behavior of the method

Tags: c#, moq

I wanted one method in mocked object to perfrom its original behavior and return a value by that behavior. But I could not make it.
The below is a sample code.

```
public interface IMyTest {
    public StringBuilder GetBuilder(string initial);
}

public class MyTest : IMyTest {
    public StringBuilder GetBuilder(string initial) {
        return new StringBuilder(initial + initial);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MyTestTest {
    [Test]
    public void GetBuilderTest() {
        Mock<IMyTest> obj = new() {
            CallBase = true
        };

        obj.Setup(x => x.GetBuilder(It.IsAny<string>())).CallBase();
        var a = obj.Object.GetBuilder("ABC");
        TestContext.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

So I have created a mock object of `IMyTest`, and wanted let the `GetBuilder()` method to do the actual original behavior of doubling the input string.

I thought the `CallBase()` is for such a purpose, but it raises an error like:

> This is a DynamicProxy2 error: The interceptor attempted to 'Proceed' for method 'System.Text.StringBuilder GetBuilder(System.String)' which has no target. When calling method without target there is no implementation to 'proceed' to and it is the responsibility of the interceptor to mimic the implementation (set return value, out arguments etc)

Because I am still new to Moq, I might be misunderstanding, but could not find an answer by googling. So if you could kindly help on my question.

Of course, it can use the `Return()` with the same `new StringBuilder(initial + initial)` in it, but please think that method is doing very complex work inside of it actually that I do not want to mimic it manually.

Comment: Call base works on an actual class, not an interface like in your example

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) based on the oversimplified example.

Comment: The error message also clearly states the problem. You are trying to call base on a member that has no target implementation since it is an interface.

Comment: @Nkosi, no it doesn't state it clearly unless you are very firm with internal Moq terminology which OP already said he isn't. A clear message would have been: "You're trying to use `CallBase` on a mock target that has no base implementation: Couldn't find implementation for `GetBuilder()` on `IMyTest` or its ancestors."

Comment: Thank you for the replies both, and you are right Good Night Nerd Pride, a question mark was popping up in my head by that error message. Thank you for the easy expression.

I have just tried it again by changing the interface to the class. Then, got the error `Non-overridable members (here: MyTest.GetBuilder) may not be used in setup / verification expressions`, but could run successfully with `virtual`. Does this mean we always need methods to have `virtual` to test in Moq? What should we do if a method is by a third-party in DLL?

Comment: I found some articles in the Internt about non-virtual method in Moq saying it is no possible. It looks it is not the case covered by Moq. 
Just, I found one article below.  
https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2020/10/04/mocking-non-virtual-methods-of-a-class/
But it is almost tweek as a last resort. Maybe, I should do mimicing the return value somehow (like deserializing an actual result saved as a file that is generated by running it once actually and serialized as the file) with a simple `Return()`.